# Anyone have any idea what type of receiver/transmitter that is

Tags: transmitter, receiver

I got those from someone and it does not come with any kind of datasheets

I’m guessing they are receiver and transmitter as they both have kind of an antenna.. anyone have an idea of the model so I could google the datasheets

Thanks![image]

[image]

Comment: I can't read the chips. Can you get a better picture?

Comment: And please crop your photos for the benefit of readers using small screens.

Comment: I got a clearer one, updated the question

Comment: looks like an RF transmitter/receiver ... i don't see any IR emitters/detectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a "GWB T400 2.4GHz tranceiver kit" or similar.

Chipset is LT89xx.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciated